# how to test an executable in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

Every time, when I deal with writing Tests in .NET (C#), I read, you can test DLLs only. But my app hasn't any DLLs and I want test some controllers and behaviours too. How it is possible, without creating an DLL project? Is it possible?

Hints are welcome.

Comment: Where did you read this from? Did you try?

Comment: FYI: You should always keep in mind that you can write *integration tests* on any accessible part, but you can write *unit tests* only if you designed your classes to be unit testable (all dependecies must be injectable and mockable). Both have the same lookalike but different intentions and different rules

Answer (score 1):

Your unit test project(s) can still reference application projects like any other class library.  It may be considered less ideal, but there's nothing preventing it from working.  As the logic of your system grows, even a little bit, you'll certainly want to consider moving the business logic into Class Library projects and keeping the application layer as thin as possible.

> I read, you can test DLLs only.

This was an oversimplification.  What they *probably meant* was that you can test discrete functionality only.  Regardless of what kind of project is hosting that functionality, the functionality itself has to be well defined, with separated concerns, and individually testable.  If *that's* causing a problem in your design, then you have more work to do in order to unit test your code.

But to get started, simply create your unit test project and reference your other project.  Then start writing tests for your individual units of functionality.  Each test should be testing only one discrete thing, and should consist of the simple steps of:

1. Arrange
2. Act
3. Assert

Unit tests shouldn't require any additional setup, nor should they produce any side effects.  This is where the "discrete" part comes in, each one should be individual and not depend on others.